# Manipulate some lines in a txt-file

Tags: python, file, match

I have a file with words and numbers and some file with only words. First file looks like this:

```
Cow; 39402
Horse; 2039
Pig; 2494
Snake; 39485
Monkey; 9309348
```

Second file looks like:

```
Monkey
Horse
Bird
Pig
Donkey
Monkey
```

I want to add the numbers of the first file to the words of the second file. As you may see, not all items from the second file are part of the first file. When this is the case, I want to print the word without the numbers. So my final txt-file will look like:

```
Monkey; 9309348 
Horse; 2039
Bird
Pig; 2494
Donkey
Monkey; 9309348
Cow; 39402
```

This is what i tried:

```
f = open("wordsonly.txt", "r")
flist = f.readlines()
d = open("wordsandnumbers.txt", "r")
dlist = d.readlines()

nf = open("finalfile.txt", "w")
for line in f:
    for item in dlist:
        newitem = item.rstrip('\n')
        if newitem in line:
            splitline = newitem.split(';')
            newline = line.rstrip('\n')+';'+splitline[1]+'\n'
            nf.write(newline)
            break
        a += 1
        lengthlist = len(dlist)
        if line.rstrip('\n') not in newline:
           if a == lengthlist:
              nf.write(line)
```

However, this code gives in some cases too much results (more than one for each line), I have no idea why...

(I simplified my code a bit so there may be some minor errors. I'm sorry for that)

Comment: would You consider to use dict for storing numbers for each word? or file is too big?

Comment: what os are you running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First You should create `dict` for all words with numbers as values and words as keys

```
with open("wordsandnumbers.txt", "r") as file1:
    numbers = {k:v.strip() for k,v in (line.split(';') for line in file1)}
```

then You can just create new file writing either word (if it has no number) or word with number

```
with open("wordsonly.txt", "r") as f:
    with open("finalfile.txt", "w") as nf:
        for line in f:
            line = line.strip():
            if line in numbers:
                nf.write('{}; {}\n'.format(line, numbers[line])
            else:
                nf.write('{}\n'.format(line))
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't knew it was that easy to create a dictionary!